Visual Studio 2022: Unable to change target to WSL2 Fedora Remix instance (Echo command failing)
I am having an issue connecting Visual Studio 2022 to WSL 2 with the Fedora Remix 40.1.0 distribution on Windows 11, using the procedure described here. Visual Studio is not able to connect to the WSL instance.
This is a similar issue as the one in this post, except that instead of using Ubuntu in WSL 2 I use Fedora Remix.
If I reinstall Fedora Remix without creating a user, hence having a root account with no password, Visual Studio is able to connect to WSL, which makes me think that Visual Studio is not able to find the WSL Fedora username somehow. I also tried to create a WSL Fedora username and password exactly the same as for the Windows account, but that did not help.
I would prefer to have a proper user account in WSL. Does anyone know how to configure Visual Studio to make it work?
